# insert multiple select statement values into a single column?

Tags: mysql, select

I have an old table with multiple columns storing names, the names may be repeated many times throughout the table. And I wanted to select all the names in each of the columns, throw away the repeated one, and insert them into a new table.

Right now I can only do it one select statement at a time, and the DISTINCT function doesn't carry on between each select statement, so I ended up with repeated names. I'm using MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO new_table (name)
SELECT DISTINCT old_table.name
FROM old_table
WHERE blah blah blah

INSERT INTO new_table (name)
SELECT DISTINCT old_table.name2
FROM old_table
WHERE blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with an UNION clause, it will distinct all repeated values -

```
SELECT name FROM old_table
  UNION
SELECT name2 FROM old_table
  UNION
SELECT name3 FROM old_table
```

Apply it to INSERT...SELECT query -

```
INSERT INTO new_table(name)
  SELECT name FROM old_table
    UNION
  SELECT name2 FROM old_table
    UNION
  SELECT name3 FROM old_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table and insert the names into the table first and try DISTINCT selection from the temporary table.

Create a temp table:

```
create temporary table dummy (name text);
```

Do all your INSERTS:

```
INSERT INTO dummy (name)
SELECT DISTINCT old_table.name
FROM old_table
WHERE blah blah blah;
```

And finally

```
INSERT into new_table(name) 
select distinct dummy.name
from dummy;
```